# Synchronize HTML between browser and server

Tags: html, ajax, synchronization

When showing a very big unordered list in a web application, how might one keep that list in sync with a server-generated (and memoized) copy while neither re-overwriting the entire list with Ajax (and hence sending the entire list over the wire) nor paginating?

Comment: Any code? What have you done so far?

Comment: You could expand and clarify your question with what needs to be kept in sync and why. Will the page be changing because of the user? Will the server side be changing because of other users? Why is simply refreshing the page not an option in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poll the server at a regular interval that the server script compares the previous list with the new list and sends back the difference. Finally, change the list according to the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `websockets` to keep a *persistant connection* between the client's browser and your page. When a change occurs server side, only the element that has changed could be sent to the client page for refreshing the view in a push way.

This is very powerfull but needs your client's browser to be compatible with HTML5's websockets. Nevertheless, they are many frameworks that allows you to use alternate ways when websockets are not available, a famous one is [`Socket.io`](http://socket.io). This framework has been designed to work on top of [`Node.js`](http://nodejs.org/), one of the most used server for dealing with websockets.